# How to use jquery library in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, jquery

I am creating a Magento theme where I need to include jQuery.

When I add this `<link src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"/>` in `head`. It is working but Magento javascript functions are not working. How to use the Magento 2 built in jQuery library on a custom theme?

Comment: jquery is already added to m2. If you need jquery in your custom phtml file then use it by require.js

Comment: yes i know that i want to use in custom theme.. i have file that are dependent on jquery library.

Comment: use 
require([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui'], function($){}

Comment: you can add extrnal js by using <script src="[Vendor_Ext]::js/custom.js"/>

Comment: Since when do you include js by `link` tag??? You have to use script tag

Comment: you can understand jquery issues with this post [how to use jquery in magento 2](https://www.mageants.com/blog/how-to-use-jquery-in-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you are adding your custom js library other than jQuery then you need to include the js code inside require function like:

```
 require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
     //your js code here  
 });
```

### Examples:

Inside the require function, you can directly access jQuery functionality in place by using either `jQuery` or its short form alias, the dollar `$` sign. For example:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
```

Here is an example with the `$` alias:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(document).ready( function() {
    alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to include prototype.js ?

Comment: @Vikram, Yeah, just add 'prototype' element to the array that you pass to require() function.

Answer (score 5):

Jquery/JqueryUI have added in magento2. You can see in lib/web/jquery

To use jquery or call widget of magento. From your js file

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui',
  'mage/<widget.name>' found in /lib/web/mage dir
], function($){

$.widget('<your_namespace>.<your_widget_name>', $.mage.<widget.name>, {  CODE HERE... });

return $.<your_namespace>.<your_widget_name>;

});
```

Comment: i tried that and it is not working can you place something according to theme.