# Adding a jQuery Library to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

How can a third party developer add a jQuery library to Magento 2?

While Magento 2 includes a version of jQuery in their frontend themes, the jQuery object **is not** immediately available in the global namespace.  I belive this is because Magento 2 uses RequireJS to pull in jQuery, and RequireJS won't load a module file until its needed.

This presents a problem for jQuery plugins. Normally, I'd include a plugin with HTML that looked something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://magento-1-9-2-2.dev/js/commercebug/jquery-ui-1.8.custom/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

This, however, is not possible with Magento 2.  Because the `jquery.cookie.js` file defines the jQuery plugin by using the global jQuery object, it will fail in Magento 2 with a `jQuery is not defined` error.

How should a front end developer include a standard jquery plugin library in Magento 2's front end application?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-to-use-jquery-library-in-magento-2  maybe helpful

Comment: @QaisarSatti No, that's not helpful in this context?  It shows how to use the main jquery library, and use Magento widget.  It doesn't say anything about how to pull in a standard jquery plugin.

Comment: @AlanStorm you want to add Jquery without using RequireJs?

Comment: @ShaheerAli No, I want to use the jQuery that ships with Magento 2, and use a third party jquery plugin that **doesn't** ship with Magento 2

Comment: @AlanStrom you need to put your third party plugin js code between the require js function in your js file like require([ 'jquery'], function($){ //your plugin code here  });

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create requirejs-config.js 
Companyname\Modulename\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js
add

```
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           bannerslider: 'Companyname_Modulename/js/flexslider',
       }
   }
};
```

Your Js file in your module 
Companyname\Modulename\view\frontend\web\js\flexslider.js
You just add jquery lib using following syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','bannerslider'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider-8').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            controlNav: "thumbnails",
            slideshowSpeed: 2000,
            minItems: 2,
            maxItems: 4
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

second example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
            alert('jquery working');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How does the flexslider javascript file get include into the HTML page and/or requireJS?

Comment: You can add using require js.if you want i describe in detail

Comment: @AlanStorm please accept answer if you are clear if not let me know i share more information :)

Comment: Even though this works, the "jQuery is not defined" error still pops up every half dozen page refreshes.

Comment: Alan has done a great breakdown of the issue in his blog post: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs

Comment: @themanwhoknowstheman how did you solve this issue? To me, it doesn't happen exactly the same, but it just won't go inside $(window).load function sometimes (when refreshing only with f5).

Comment: This is NOT a correct way to do this, see Lance's answer

Answer (score 6):

I quote the [Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html).

To build a dependency on the third-party plugin, specify a shim in the following configuration files:

In your requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
  "shim": {
     "3-rd-party-plugin": ["jquery"]
    }
  };
```

Then include your third party plugin code in your Theme or Module: "web/js/3-rd-party-plugin.js" like so:

```
!(function($){
  // plugin code
  // where $ == jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

This solution is favorable because you are including your plugin file without any kind of modification.Simply replace the js file when the plugin author updates or even use a cdn!

Answer (score 5):

Best thing to do is use a Magento 2 **Module** or a **Theme** to include such plugins/libraries. **It is the recommended way and the best practice**.

---

**Method 1 > THEME**: If the ***javascript/jquery*** library is theme related (In order to change the look and feel of the system).

- Place the custom component source file in one of the following location
  **[theme_dir]/web/js/**
- Place your **requirejs-config.js** file in 
   **[theme_dir]**

---

**Method 2 > MODULE**: If the ***javascript/jquery*** library is related to a particular business function or handles a Magento feature. It should go inside a module.

- Place the custom component source file in one of the following location 
  **[module_dir]/view/frontend/web/js/**
- Place your **requirejs-config.js** file in 
   **[module_dir]/view/frontend/**

> Magento 2 strongly recommends not changing the source code of default
>   Magento components and widgets. All customizations must be implemented
>   in custom modules or themes.

Answer (score 4):

Alan, jQuery UI Widget factory has a special case. To make AMD compatible please check the following link.

http://gregfranko.com/blog/registering-the-jqueryui-widget-factory-as-an-amd-module/