# Add jQuery plugin without for whole site without a module (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, jquery, plugin

How can I add a jQuery plugin without a module for use in the whole site.

I found things about how to add it in modules:
[Adding a jQuery Library to Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98250/adding-a-jquery-library-to-magento-2)

But can I add it without a module and if yes in which should requirejs-config.js be placed?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is use a Magento 2 **Module** or a **Theme** to include such plugins/libraries. **It is the recommended way and the best practice**. Is there anything blocking you from doing that? If so, pls share.

---

**Method 1 > THEME**: If the ***javascript/jquery*** library is theme related (In order to change the look and feel of the system).

- Place the custom component source file in one of the following location
  **[theme_dir]/web/js/**
- Place your **requirejs-config.js** file in 
   **[theme_dir]**

---

**Method 2 > MODULE**: If the ***javascript/jquery*** library is related to a particular business function or handles a Magento feature. It should go inside a module.

- Place the custom component source file in one of the following location 
  **[module_dir]/view/frontend/web/js/**
- Place your **requirejs-config.js** file in 
   **[module_dir]/view/frontend/**

> Magento 2 strongly recommends not changing the source code of default
>   Magento components and widgets. All customizations must be implemented
>   in custom modules or themes.

---

---

***[EDITED: To provide a example as per in the first comment]***

Using method 1 for including a js file.

File: `[Root_Dir]/app/code/[NameSpace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            faq:'Namespace_Module/js/faq'
        }
    }
};
```

Then the file related to this mapping will be there on the same module directory.

File: `[Root_Dir]/app/code/[NameSpace]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/faq.js`

```
//faq.js
define([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    alert('TEST');
});
```

So the script path in the **require-config.js** file should be specified from modules view/frontend/web directory, without the ***.js*** extension.

This way, a script can be added to the frontend.
Follow the default module `./vendor/magento/module-checkout/*` or similar...

**EDIT 2:**
If you want to debug and see from where Magento is trying to pull the static file, follow the article on http://www.magleaks.com/magento-2-static-file-resolving/ and add a debug pointer to the file `[DOC_ROOT]/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/FileResolution/Fallback/Resolver/Simple.php`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying Method 1. The change in requirejs-config.js works and apears in the source code. But my js file in web/js/main.js does not apear. I added this to requiresjs-config.js: var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "js/main": {}
        }
    }
};

Comment: I'll add a sample code shortly, check that and provide more information...

Comment: I added my sample code. My problem is I don't have a module. And I try to do it in the theme. But my js does not load.

Comment: It tries to load my file only if I request it in a phtml file. Now I get it to look for my file in the pub/static folder. But that file doesn't move into the static folder and I get a 404.

Comment: I made a new entry, as it seems to be a different problem.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108484/add-jquery-plugin-waypoint-js-but-file-does-not-apear-in-static-folder-magento

Comment: Hi @OliverSchmid in your dev environment, have you turned on the developer mode? Production mode won't auto generate the content to pub/static, you have to run a magento command. Commented in the other above link.

Comment: Hi Dilhan, thanks, but yes, it is in developer mode already.