# Add jQuery plugin waypoint.js, but file does not apear in static folder (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am trying to add a jQuery Plugin waypoint.js to my theme. I did the following:

**File:** `app/design/frontend/name/themename/requirejs_config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            waypoint:'js/waypoint'
        }
    }
};
```

**JS File is here:** `app/design/frontend/name/themename/web/js/waypoint.js`

**I call it in a phtml file:**

```
require(['jquery','waypoint'],function($){

});
```

**The Chrome debugging tool shows me an error now, can't find that waypoing.js in the static folder here:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>   require.js:1895 GET 
>   `pub/static/frontend/name/themename/de_CH/waypoint.js`

The file waypoint.js does not exist in that folder. How to bring it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way that seems to work.

First requirejs_config.js is not needed. I remove it.

All you need to do is ad the js file here: `app/design/frontend/name/themename/web/js/waypoint.js`

Now you can can call it from every phtml file. Just wrap this around it:

```
require(['jquery','js/waypoint'],function($){

});
```

This works for me. Probably I will add my js in a phtml file on the end, maybe footer.

Answer (score 0):

Under pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US, delete the file requirejs-config.js.

and run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

**DEVELOPER MODE:** Make sure to turn on the developer mode when you are in the development environment. Then **Magento generates the static content** files run time *(when the static resource is requested)* and place them in the pub/static directory accordingly.

To do that:

1. Apache .htaccess file of the root directory you are using **[MAGENTO_ROOT]/.htaccess** or **[MAGENTO_ROOT]/pub/.htaccess**, uncomment the line

   `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer`
2. NginX: Uncomment the following line on the `server {}`  directive

   `server {
      listen 80;
      server_name SERVER_NAME;
      set $MAGE_ROOT ROOT_DIR;
      set $MAGE_MODE developer; #This line will turn on developer mode
      include file.conf;
   }`

**PRODUCTION MODE:** You must turn off the developer mode when going live. and use `production` mode. This way Magento won't create missing static content in the `pub/static` directory. Hence you will get 404 page. You have to manually deploy the static content.

```
`SetEnv MAGE_MODE production # Apache .htaccess`
`set $MAGE_MODE production; # NginX`
```

For every deployment you make to the live server, you have to run

```
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
```

So that Magento will go through each module and generate the necessary static files in the `pub/static` directory