# Slider with Collections

Tags: magento2

Everyone, I wanted to insert the Product collection in my Slider for this purpose I'm using JQuery script (In the theme Header) with the HTML and CSS. The Error is "$ signed undefined" while I'm doing inspect-->Console! The below example was trying to implement. kindly guide me!
[image]

Comment: hello @Adeel Please $sign replace into jQuery

Comment: more refer this may be help you :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-to-use-jquery-library-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Jquery and js cannot be use directly in magento 2

so you have to do something like that

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  //all you jquery code here
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
require(['jquery'],function($){ $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() { var next = $(this).next(); if (!next.length) { next = $(this).siblings(':first'); } next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)); for (var i = 0; i &lt; 3; i++) { next = next.next(); if (!next.length) { next = $(this).siblings(':first'); } next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)); } }); });
<script>
// ]]></script>

Answer (score 0):

You have to created one requirejs-config.js file inside your theme like,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            owlcarousel: 'Solwin_Module1/js/owl.carousel'
        }
    }
};
```

And then you need to include the js code inside require function like:

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'owlcarousel'], function () {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        pagination : false
         });
    });
});
</script>
```